# Strange new lines and spaces in email sent by php

Tags: php

I send emails to users on certain occasions (e.g. when they change their passwords). I have a strange problem which is as below: I have no idea why but sometimes there is a new line (or style is ignored probably) somewhere in the code. Even if I don't change a thing, I receive different emails. A similar problem is when there is an extra space between characters.

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table class="reg_mail">';
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td class="hi" style="padding-top:10px;">';
    $message .= '<p>Hi '.$user.',</p>';
$message .= '</td>';
$message .= '</tr>';
//bla bla bla
$message .= '<tr>';
$message .= '<td class="hi" style="padding-top:10px;">';
    $message .= '<pAll rights reserved</p>';
$message .= '</td>';
$message .= '</tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

So this is basically the email. I sent the email twice to my email address, and in the first one I got "All rights reserved" and in the second one I get "All rights res erved". What is going on?
Other times when I have a table with seven rows in the mail, one of the rows them looks like to ignore the  `margin:0` code.

Is this a common problem, or my code is wrong?

**Edit:**

Sending mail:

```
$mail_from = "donotreply@website.com";
$headers = "From: \"Website\" <$mail_from>\r\n" .
  "Reply-To: $mail_from\r\n" .
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail($form_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: A typo, I hope `$message .= '<pAll rights reserved</p>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included the code of actually sending the mail, 
but perhaps you've forgotten to break message into 70-character lines?

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
```

Alternatively: add `"\r\n"` into your string manually, e.g.

```
$message = '<html><body>' . "\r\n";
$message .= '<table class="reg_mail">' . "\r\n";
// ...
```

Comment: I have added the relevant code block. What is this message break?

Comment: From [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): "`$message` - Message to be sent. Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters."

Comment: It's working now without this and with this as well. I guess I am just lucky now. I will get back about this later. Btw, it's much easier to add that wordwrap line after '$message .= '</body></html>';'

Comment: After two weeks all messages were sent without extra spaces or new lines. Thank you!